# Summarizing multiple columns with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use data.table to speed up processing of a large data.frame (300k x 60) made of several smaller merged data.frames. I'm new to data.table. The code so far is as follows

```
library(data.table)
a = data.table(index=1:5,a=rnorm(5,10),b=rnorm(5,10),z=rnorm(5,10))
b = data.table(index=6:10,a=rnorm(5,10),b=rnorm(5,10),c=rnorm(5,10),d=rnorm(5,10))
dt = merge(a,b,by=intersect(names(a),names(b)),all=T)
dt$category = sample(letters[1:3],10,replace=T)
```

and I wondered if there was a more efficient way than the following to summarize the data.

```
summ = dt[i=T,j=list(a=sum(a,na.rm=T),b=sum(b,na.rm=T),c=sum(c,na.rm=T),
                     d=sum(d,na.rm=T),z=sum(z,na.rm=T)),by=category]
```

I don't really want to type all 50 column calculations by hand and a `eval(paste(...))` seems clunky somehow.

I had a look at the example below but it seems a bit complicated for my needs. thanks

[how to summarize a data.table across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241687/summarize-a-data-table-across-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use a simple `lapply` statement with `.SD`

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=category ]

   category index        a        b        z         c        d
1:        c    19 51.13289 48.49994 42.50884  9.535588 11.53253
2:        b     9 17.34860 20.35022 10.32514 11.764105 10.53127
3:        a    27 25.91616 31.12624  0.00000 29.197343 31.71285
```

---

If you only want to summarize over certain columns, you can add the `.SDcols` argument

```
#  note that .SDcols also allows reordering of the columns
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=category, .SDcols=c("a", "c", "z") ] 

   category        a         c        z
1:        c 51.13289  9.535588 42.50884
2:        b 17.34860 11.764105 10.32514
3:        a 25.91616 29.197343  0.00000
```

---

This of course, is not limited to `sum` and you can use any function with `lapply`, including anonymous functions. (ie, it's a regular `lapply` statement).

Lastly, there is no need to use `i=T` and `j= <..>`.  Personally, I think that makes the code less readable, but it is just a style preference.

---

### Documentation

See `?.SD`, `?data.table` and its `.SDcols` argument, and the vignette [Using .SD for Data Analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-sd-usage.html).

Also have a look at `data.table` [FAQ 2.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#how-can-i-avoid-writing-a-really-long-j-expression-youve-said-that-i-should-use-the-column-names-but-ive-got-a-lot-of-columns.).

Comment: what if you want several aggregation functions for different collumns? For example you want the sum for collumn a and the mean for collumn b

Comment: answer on my question: 
`DT[, .(agra = sum(a), agrb = mean(b)), by=category]`

Comment: Is there a way to also automatically make the column names "sum a" , "sum b", " sum c" in the lapply?

Comment: Is there now a different way than using .SD?

Comment: @Mark You could do using data.table::setattr in this way dt[, {
  lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
  setattr(., "names", value = sprintf("sum_%s", names(.)))
  }, by=category, .SDcols=c("a", "c", "z") ]