# Use data.table to count and aggregate / summarize a column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate

I want to count and aggregate(sum) a column in a `data.table`, and couldn't find the most efficient way to do this.  This seems to be close to what I want [R summarizing multiple columns with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513827/r-summarizing-multiple-columns-with-data-table).

My data:

```
set.seed(321)
dat <- data.table(MNTH = c(rep(201501,4), rep(201502,3), rep(201503,5), rep(201504,4)), 
                  VAR = sample(c(0,1), 16, replace=T))

> dat
     MNTH VAR
 1: 201501   1
 2: 201501   1
 3: 201501   0
 4: 201501   0
 5: 201502   0
 6: 201502   0
 7: 201502   0
 8: 201503   0
 9: 201503   0
10: 201503   1
11: 201503   1
12: 201503   0
13: 201504   1
14: 201504   0
15: 201504   1
16: 201504   0
```

I want to both count and sum `VAR` by `MNTH` using data.table. The desired result:

```
    MNTH COUNT VAR
1 201501     4   2
2 201502     3   0
3 201503     5   2
4 201504     4   2
```

Comment: I find [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826378/1048186) for this question to be easier to follow even in the SINGLE column case than the [accepted answer on the question linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513827/r-summarizing-multiple-columns-with-data-table) in this question.

Comment: I think that is because the other question is pointed to a many-column case.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The post you are referring to gives a method on how to apply one aggregation method to several columns. If you want to apply different aggregation methods to different columns, you can do:

```
dat[, .(count = .N, var = sum(VAR)), by = MNTH]
```

this results in:

> ```
>      MNTH count var
> 1: 201501     4   2
> 2: 201502     3   0
> 3: 201503     5   2
> 4: 201504     4   2
> ```

You can also add these values to your existing dataset by updating your dataset by reference:

```
dat[, `:=` (count = .N, var = sum(VAR)), by = MNTH]
```

this results in:

> ```
> > dat
>       MNTH VAR count var
>  1: 201501   1     4   2
>  2: 201501   1     4   2
>  3: 201501   0     4   2
>  4: 201501   0     4   2
>  5: 201502   0     3   0
>  6: 201502   0     3   0
>  7: 201502   0     3   0
>  8: 201503   0     5   2
>  9: 201503   0     5   2
> 10: 201503   1     5   2
> 11: 201503   1     5   2
> 12: 201503   0     5   2
> 13: 201504   1     4   2
> 14: 201504   0     4   2
> 15: 201504   1     4   2
> 16: 201504   0     4   2
> ```

For further reading about how to use [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) syntax, see the [**Getting started guides**](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) on the GitHub wiki.