# How to perform calculations on each column of a data table in R

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and am getting starting with some simple calculation.

I have imported some data called BM_Returns, I am able to select a specific column and perform calculations on that column fine, how would i do it for all/a subset of the column?

example:

```
S1_Ann_ret <- (prod(1+(BM_Returns$Stock_1/100))^(1/yrs))-1
```

In my data column 1 is dates all other columns (2-15) are ones i would like to perform the above and other calculations on.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what `yrs` means in this. Is it just a constant? For future questions please consider posting a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summarizing multiple columns with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513827/summarizing-multiple-columns-with-data-table)

Comment: This contains a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16513827/6503141

Comment: Yes yrs is a constant. I'm taking a look at the answer you posted right now.
I tried Akrun's solution but i am having trouble installing dplyr

Comment: It might be helpfull to state whether you have an actual `data.table` as the heading suggest or a classic `data.frame` or a `tibble`. Nothing beats a reproducible example...

Comment: Yes it is a data table, here is a subset of it that will hopefully work for an example:
           Date R200V Index R200G Index RMV Index RDG Index RUJ Index RUO Index
  1: 12/31/2020      3.4070      4.5583    4.6230    4.7972    7.9204    9.3442
  2: 11/30/2020     13.1444      9.5536   14.0415   13.4312   19.2901   17.6272
  3: 10/30/2020     -2.4472     -4.1229    0.9304    0.1226    3.5765    0.7598
  4:  9/30/2020     -2.5523     -5.3517   -2.2652   -1.4003   -4.6532   -2.1429
  5:  8/31/2020      4.2237     11.9387    3.9595    2.7206    5.3871    5.8662

Answer (score 1):

If the calculation needs to be repeated, use `across` in `mutate`

```
libray(dplyr)
BM_Returns2 <- BM_Returns %>%
     mutate(across(2:15, ~ (prod(1 + (./100))^((1/yrs)) - 1))
```

Or use `base R`

```
BM_Returns[2:15] <- lapply(BM_Returns[2:15], function(x)
                (prod(1 + (x/100))^((1/BM_Returns$yrs)) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, i cannot get dplyr installed and running correctly this is the error i am getting:
```
> library("dplyr")
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'dplyr' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called 'lifecycle'
```
I think it might be due to a lack of permissions on my computer but am not sure.

Comment: @GT213 then, try with the `base R` updated solution